# When will RISC-V Android devices be available?

Tags: arm-processors, risc-v

Google [announced in December 2022](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/01/google-announces-official-android-support-for-risc-v/) that Android would support RISC-V devices. More recently, [Qualcomm have announced](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/10/qualcomm-announces-first-ever-mass-market-risc-v-android-soc/) that they're working on a RISC-V chipset for Wear OS with Google.

When will we be able to buy RISC-V Android devices?

Answer (score 2):

## What is [RISC-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V)?

It's a new species of CPU, which is meant to compete with ARM and x86 for general-purpose computing, including smartphones and tablets. The design work started at the University of California at Berkley, and is their fifth RISC design family, hence the name. The design seems reasonably sound, although it hasn't been built in forms that compete with the fastest ARM cores yet.

The unusual thing about it is that the essence of the design is open source, and can be used  by anyone without license fees or royalties. Many people and organisations have contributed to the design, just as happens with open source software. However, the design doesn't include a realization as electronic circuits. Organisations that want to build RISC-V processors have to design that part themselves, or license a realization from someone else.

## What are the advantages?

The simplest advantage over ARM is cost. There are no architecture license fees, although most organisations will have to pay royalties on the electronics design(s) they use.

The other advantage is that it is open source, and nobody can forbid you from using it. A few years ago, when it looked as if ARM Holdings were going to be bought by Nvidia, and thus become an American-controlled company, this was important. [Huawei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei) is one of China's largest smartphone manufacturers and a major target of US trade restrictions. They started work on porting Android to RISC-V,  so as to have a fallback if their ARM license was lost. At present, ARM Holdings has had an IPO as an independent company, and there's no *immediate* prospect of the US government requiring ARM to cut off Huawei, but that could change in the future.

Even if you're a US or European company with no fear of loosing your ARM license, having a competitor to ARM ready to go is a useful bargaining chip.

## Google's work on Android

Since RISC-V is a very modular architecture with many optional parts and extensions, Google needed to define a minimum standard so that software could be portable between devices. The first pass of that has been done and was presented at the June 2023 RISC-V summit in Europe.

However, the Android kernel team feel that RISC-V needs [better "atomic" instructions](https://github.com/google/android-riscv64/issues/44), which will require a new extension to the RISC-V instruction set.

Google's Android team need to complete the port of AOSP to reference RISC-V hardware and get it working *properly*, at the same level of quality as ARM Android. That is underway, and as of October 2023, ASOP can be built for RISC-V and run on Cuttlefish virtual devices.

The was an announcement about the above in [October 2023](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2023/10/android-and-risc-v-what-you-need-to-know.html). As of then, ART was not generating fully-optimised RISC-V code for the full Android standard, the compilers likewise weren't generating fully optimised code, and the NDK ABI wasn't released.

You can track their progress on Github [here](https://github.com/google/android-riscv64).

Here's a talk from [SiFive, a RISC-V core vendor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7uJypVFBE0) about their work with Android on RISC-V.

## Device builders' work

SoC designers who compete with Qualcomm, like Huawei and other Chinese companies, will be designing and prototyping their SoCs and getting them ready to offer to device manufacturers. With that, Android devices can be built and sold. Google expects wearables to be the first Android devices available, presumably because they don't need as much compute power as high-end smartphones or tablets.

## App suppliers' work

RISC-V Android should run pure Kotlin or Java apps just fine, once ART is complete, but it won't run NDK libraries built for ARM or x86. Rebuilding NDK libraries needs an NDK that can compile for RISC-V, plus upgrades to the Android SDK so that it knows of RISC-V and can manage the builds, and those aren't available yet. A way to tell if they are forthcoming is to check the web page that [lists Android NDK ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis). The RISC-V ABI was expected by the end of 2023, but is delayed. It is going to be based on the [RVA22 profile family](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-profiles/blob/main/profiles.adoc), which tells us that there will be no 32-bit RISC-V Android.

## Device availability?

This can't be predicted at present, because of the need for better atomic instructions. Those need to be added to the standards, and new cores designed that have them, before Android can be released.